# key type ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]

Tags: ubuntu, openssh, sshd, putty

I have trouble setting passwordless authentication on a host:

```
Sep 21 09:57:36 pvestorage2 sshd[1688625]: userauth_pubkey: key type ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
```

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- ssh server version: openssh-server 8.9p1-3
- client: Win10 + putty 0.77 and 0.79 on two systems
- key: generated with puttygen bundled with version 0.77

I am aware of putty bug related to supplying keys and I have PuTTy updated.
I am also aware of ssh-rsa deprecation, this is why I am using this key in the first place.

```
~$ ssh -Q PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms | grep nistp521
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com
```

I have added:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
```

to sshd_config in case it changes something.

I am not in liberty to reboot the remote machine for several weeks, only to restart sshd.

I kind of have no idea how to make it work. What did I miss?

Comment: Did you generate such a key at the server, too? // Did you assure the private key's  access rights *"not read/writeable by group or world"*? // Did you configure the keyfile  in the `sshd_config` by an entry `HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa-sha2-nistp521_key`? // Just restarting the `sshd` should be fine to get the new `sshd_config` re-read.

Comment: >> Did you generate such a key at the server, too? //

No. I generated the key using puttygen and copied over to Ubuntu host.

>> Did you assure the private key's access rights "not read/writeable by group or world"? //

You mean authorized_keys file? Yes.

>> Did you configure the keyfile in the sshd_config by an entry HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa-sha2-nistp521_key? //

No, I didn't. Why would I? Never did it anywhere and never had any problems.

>> Just restarting the sshd should be fine to get the new sshd_config re-read. //

Thank you.